# Form submitting using Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using multiple form in a page here is my HTML code:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="test.php">
<a href="javascript: submitform();" >submit</a>
<input type="hidden" name="encKey" value="12" />
</form>

<form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="test.php">
<a href="javascript: submitform();" >submit</a>
<input type="hidden" name="encKey" value="12" />
</form>


<form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="test.php">
<a href="javascript: submitform();" >submit</a>
<input type="hidden" name="encKey" value="12" />
</form>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

When i click on submit link, form is not submitting and gererate error in backend:

> TypeError: document.myform.submit is not a function.

What may be issue?

Thanks

Comment: IDs and name attribute are meant to be unique.. forms are not attached to the document object directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use unique ids for all the forms. Then you can have a function that takes as a parameter the id of the form that you want to submit and then submit it. So you can have something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(formid)
{
  document.getElementById(formid).submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.getElementById('myform').submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the **id** of a form must be unique, try to change the form id to only name.

you can try to use

```
document.getElementById('formId').submit()
```

to submit the information of a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `document.forms["myForm"].submit();`.
In this case `"myForm"` is the name of each form and it has to be unique as well as id.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you've got 3 id which are the same (myform), an id has to be unique.